# Apache poi calculating cell address

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

How to get cell address when cell is null?

lets say i have the following excel

```
  A B C D
1 x x x x
2 x x   x
3 x x x x
```

When I am iterating inside a row over columns
something like:

```
    for (i in 0 until lastCellNum) {
     val cell = row.getCell(i)
     if (cell != null){
       println(cell.address)
     } else {
       println("cell data is missing at address: "+ //address_calculation)
     }    
    }
```

How to print this?:

> "cell data is missing at address: C2"

Comment: Fetch with a missing cell policy of https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html#CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK then you'll always get a blank cell back?

Comment: this will put the cell into the sheet which I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

If I create a celladdress by hand it will calculate it:

```
CellAddress(rowIndex,colIndex).formatAsString
```